# Facebook Authentication Policies, what information could be retrieved?

Tags: facebook, authentication, policy

I'm trying to implement Facebook login to my website. I found a nice example here.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/   but by following that example I don't get the "login with facebook" button with facebook theme (blue and white color) just as like when I just use:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" >Login with Facebook</div>
```

The example just use a plain html button. Is there a way to render a facebook login button by using the example on the link above? I know may be this is just a matter of creativity, any help would be appreciated. What bothers me actually, if I use the  instead, how to render a facebook logout button. Because what I read here http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies   in **Features and Functionality** section point number 6 states that we must explicitly provide a log out button that will log out the user from Facebook too.

What could be retrieve from the response of FB.api('/me', function(response)? From the example above, I could retrieve the id and name of the authenticated user, what other information could I retrieve? could I retrieve gender, birthdate, etc..

Thanks.

Comment: You mixed too much in one place, it's really better to separate what you asking as different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get gender birthdays etc from graph API.

please take your time and explore the info at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/   .

with proper access token you can get most useful informations.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read documentation of [`user` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) of [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to get more information about fields of that object, since `me` is an alias to current user it have every field just like any other `user` object.